# Pass maven argument in jenkins pipeline shell command

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a doubt on the below issue can someone please help me on this.

I wanted to pass maven pom.xml properties from the shell in jenkins pipeline which needs to  be substituted by maven and not by groovy or shell.

Example:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -Doracle.db.url=${db.url} package'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here **${db.url}** should be substituted by the url from maven setting.xml file properties and not by groovy or shell in Jenkins pipeline.
I have tried different combination but it gives me error in Jenkins pipeline.

If the above maven property is constant(some constant url) then it is easy to pass but when I wanted to pass any variable property (**${db.url}**) then I am not able to do so with any syntax.

Comment: `$` has a different meaning in groovy, Hence groovy will try to evaluate. if you want Maven to evaluate, add an escape sequence character sh `mvn -Doracle.db.url=\\${db.url} package`

Answer (score 0):

If you want maven to evaluate `${db.url}`, it has to be like

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -Doracle.db.url=\\${db.url} package'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you see, Jenkins will prepare the maven command like this-

[image]

If you don't escape it will  give you `Bad substitution` error